# Forward and backward fourier transform image in java

Tags: java, libraries, third-party-libraries

Can anyone suggest a java library to perform forward and backward Fourier transform on images? Either RGB or gray-scale or binary , that doesn't matter since I've converted the image to all these ;)

I do searched but most of the image processing libraries like marvin, JAI etc don't have Fourier transform. So I thought anyone who have done this earlier could suggest me one

Comment: What do you mean by "good"? Can you add some criteria with which to evaluate libraries?

Comment: @AnnaLear As of now, I would appreciate anything! ;)  I dint thought the word good will do any harm ;)

Comment: @AnnaLear btw, removed good ;)

Comment: Well, the point to Anna's comment wasn't removing the word itself, but: `Can you add some criteria with which to evaluate libraries?`. If you are just looking for any library, without any specific parameters, did you try searching first?

Comment: @YannisRizos I do searched but most of the image processing libraries don't have Fourier transform. So I thought anyone who 've done this earlier could suggest me one :) I do understand Anna but I'd appreciate anything, that's why I removed the word good ;)

Comment: Add that to the question, with a couple of examples of libraries that you found that don't fit your needs and why, to better guide answeres to what you are looking for... You may have searched, but how was anyone to know if you don't tell us in the question?

Comment: @YannisRizos Edited the answer and Thanks for helping me out, rather than down-voting and walking away!

Answer (score 2):

[JAI (Java Advanced Imaging API)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Advanced_Imaging) has classes `DFTDescriptor` and `IDFTDescriptor` which seem to match.

- [API docs for DFTDescriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/operator/DFTDescriptor.html) describe it as follows:

  > ...The "DFT" operation computes the discrete Fourier transform of an image.
- for inverse transform, there is [IDFTDescriptor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/operator/IDFTDescriptor.html):

  > ...The "IDFT" operation computes the inverse discrete Fourier transform of an image.

Answer (score 1):

[JTransforms](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms) is probably the fastest Java FFT library around. It's a generic (not particularly "image") DFT (and DCT and DST and DHT) transformer and works on `double[]` arrays so you would need to implement the image -> double[] -> image transforms yourself though.